# Postgresql db query returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I am trying to query a postgresql database from node.js using pg node. The issue is that it keeps returning an empty array without an error message. I am using PGAdmin installed on my computer as the software for the database. Please I need help. Here is the code below

```js
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import consolidate from 'consolidate';
import dust from 'dustjs-helpers';
import {Client} from 'pg';


let app = express();

//Create DB connection string
//postgres://username:password@localhost/database;
// let conn = "postgresql://knowshare:gemshare@localhost:46713/recipebookdb";
const client = new Client({
 user: 'Knowshare',
 host: 'localhost',
 database: 'recipebookdb',
 password: 'gemshare',
 port: 3005
});
client.connect();

//assign Dust Engine to .dust files
app.engine('dust', consolidate.dust);

//Set default extension to .dust
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

//set public filder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
 console.log('i got here');
 client.query('SELECT * from recipes', (dbErr, dbRes)=>{
  if(dbErr){
   console.log(dbErr);
  }else{
   res.render('index', {recipes: dbRes.rows});
   console.log("********************\nRows:", dbRes.rows, "\n********************");
  }
  client.end();
 });
 // res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
 console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: as far as I know, the default port for postgresq is 5432, where you got 3005?

Comment: I changed the port during installation. Actually when I console.log the result, it comes out with the description of the table.